# Bad latency on windows compared to mac using TCP in java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, latency

I'm trying to make a game with a multiplayer aspect, but before I dived in head on, I've been trying to get a simple ping-like application to work. For some reason, I'm getting really bad ping times (400ms or so) on Windows, whereas if I try it on a Mac, it's much, much better (8ms or so).

I've got my server and my client. The server creates a `Socket clientSock` using `serverSock.accept()`, with `serverSock` being another `Socket` at port 12234. The client connects to that at my external ip port 12234 using another `Socket` in a separate application.

My ping basically just sends a message of the current system time on my client to the server, and the server sends that right back, where the client subtracts the new current time from the one it received back and prints that out.

Java is up to date on all of the computers I tryed it on (3 windows computers, 2 macs, and a windows virtual machine).

Strangely enough, the Windows VM got the same 8 or 9 ms ping that the macs did, whereas the standalone Windows machines were in the 400ms range.

Another strange quirk is that if I ping faster, the ping time decreases to around 200ms on Windows.

Also when I ping my external address on the command line/terminal, it's around 1ms for both windows and mac.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are both the Windows and the OSX machines on the same network? Are the Windows systems running some kind of firewall? Anything else that could differ between the systems that could be network related? Also, you do count the latency the same way on both Windows and OSX?

Comment: All the machines are on the same network. I'm fairly certain that the Windows machines have a firewall, just because they have a firewall by default right? I'm not sure how it differs from windows to mac. Can you think of any other diagnostic tools to test something like that?

Comment: The latency is counted in the same way, assuming that the java clock works on both systems.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your help. I've figured it out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

As it turns out, Windows uses Nagle's algorithm to conserve bandwidth. However the algorithm institutes a **200ms** buffer time before packets are actually sent.

The reason for slow ping time on Windows is a result of this. The ~400ms times are 200ms going out from the client and then 200ms going out from the server back to the client.

**All of this can be solved by calling** `setTcpNoDelay()` on the sockets at both ends.

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0294.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay(boolean)

Comment: For high throughput and low latency games almost uniformly uses UDP for game-related communication. TCP is for non-critical things like chat, or for things that must be delivered but there are no latency constraints.